# Toggle 4 divs and display them in full width of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this page that contains 4 columns that are 25% width and 100% height each and 4 buttons to toggle each one of them. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to make them resize accordingly.

When 4 columns are visible each should be 25% wide
When 3 columns are visible each should be 33% wide
and so on ...
But when I toggle the hidden ones to be visible again they need to adjust accordingly, any suggestions ?

I created a snippet for my issue.

```js
$("#button-column-1").click(function() {
  $("#column-1").toggle(1500);
});

$("#button-column-2").click(function() {
  $("#column-2").toggle(1500);
});

$("#button-column-3").click(function() {
  $("#column-3").toggle(1500);
});

$("#button-column-4").click(function() {
  $("#column-4").toggle(1500);
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head> </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div id="button-container">
      
      <button type="button" id="button-column-1">Column 1</button>
      <button type="button" id="button-column-2">Column 2</button>
      <button type="button" id="button-column-3">Column 3</button>
      <button type="button" id="button-column-4">Column 4</button>
      
    </div>
    
    
  
    <div class="column" id="column-1">
      1
    </div>  
     <div class="column" id="column-2">
      2
    </div> 
     <div class="column" id="column-3">
      3
    </div> 
     <div class="column" id="column-4">
      4
    </div> 
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Well you can either use a bit of CSS voodoo dubbed [“quantity queries”](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) - or you simply count how many elements are visible, and set a class on the parent element accordingly., that formats those elements to be 25, 33 or whatever % wide.

Answer (score 3):

Use of [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) goes perfectly with your layout. Wrap your columns in a block element, I used a section, and then add the following CSS:

```
/* This is the element that contains the columns */
#setB {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  justify-content: center;

 }
/* This ruleset will make the columns stretch and shrink when there's empty or less space. They will start adjusting when they are 24% or more in width.
.column {
  flex: 1 1 24%;
  ...
```

#### SNIPPET

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  $("#col1").toggle(1500);
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
  $("#col2").toggle(1500);
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
  $("#col3").toggle(1500);
});

$("#btn4").click(function() {
  $("#col4").toggle(1500);
});
```

```css
#setB {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.column {
  flex: 1 1 24%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <fieldset id="setA">

    <button id="btn1">Column 1</button>
    <button id="btn2">Column 2</button>
    <button id="btn3">Column 3</button>
    <button id="btn4">Column 4</button>

  </fieldset>


  <section id='setB'>
    <div class="column" id="col1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col3">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col4">
      4
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: WoW you answer is amazing, but it's quite a lot for me a begginer to chew but I will really try to understand this and keep in mind in the future

Comment: Thanks, but it's just basic flexbox. I only added 4 lines to your CSS and one extra element to your HTML, the rest of the code is yours. I did change some names and tags in order to save some typing but those changes are superfluous. You should seriously consider using flexbox.

Comment: @SpiRT flexbox's compatibility is actually almost complete, with the exception for IE, but the 4 flexbox properties used in my answer are basic ones that even IE doesn't have a problem with that I know of. Thanks for the link, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

change css width after toggling

https://jsfiddle.net/zprLtoj8/

```
$("#button-column-1").click(function() {
  $("#column-1").toggle(1500, function() {
       columnCalc();
  });
});

$("#button-column-2").click(function() {
  $("#column-2").toggle(1500, function() {
       columnCalc();
  });
});

$("#button-column-3").click(function() {
  $("#column-3").toggle(1500, function() {
       columnCalc();
  });
});

$("#button-column-4").click(function() {
  $("#column-4").toggle(1500, function() {
       columnCalc();
  });
});

function columnCalc () {
    $(".column").css('width', 100/$(".column:visible").length+'%'); 
}
```

update

such code will change column width of the .column to 33%
$(".column").css('width', '33%');

for dynamic changes we have to know how many of .column
are visible now 
we can count it like this
$(".column:visible").length

so we are dividing 100 block width on visible .column count
100/$(".column:visible").length

as css property is in % we have to add it
100/$(".column:visible").length+'%')

and so we have final code
$(".column").css('width', 100/$(".column:visible").length+'%');

Also we have to wait until animation end to do calculations

```
.toggle(1500, function() {
       columnCalc();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But please can you explain me this part please ? 
$(".column").css('width', 100/$(".column:visible").length+'%');